# How Do I Serialize DateTime Objects in .NET in a Standards Compliant Way

Tags: .net, datetime, standards-compliance

My goal is use the .NET DateTime object (in C#) and have that be serialized to and parsed from a string (for use in XML) in a way that is standards compliant. The specific standard I have in mind is the ISO 8601 standard for representing dates and times.

I want an easy to use solution (preferably, one method call each way)
 that will convert to and from the concatenated version of the format. I would also like to preserve local time zone information.

Here's an example of the sort of string I'd like to get:

2009-04-15T10:55:03.0174-05:00

My target .NET version is 3.5.

I actually found a solution to this problem several years ago which involves a custom format and the DateTime.ToString(string) method. I was surprised that a simpler standards compliant solution didn't exist. Using a custom format string to serialize and parse in a standards compliant way smells a little to me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Fortunately, there is `XmlConvert.ToString()` and `XmlConvert.ToDateTime()` which handles this format:

```
string s = XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime.Now,
     XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Local);
DateTime dt = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(s,
     XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Local);
```

(pick your appropriate serialization-mode)

Comment: you old-timers are sure quick on the draw. :-)

Answer (score 5):

`dateobj.ToString("s")` will get you an ISO 8601-compliant string representation, which can then be deserialized with `DateTime.Parse()`

Answer (score 4):

It looks like .NET has improved a little in this regard over the past few years. The [System.Xml.XmlConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.aspx) object seems to be designed to address a whole class of needs that appear in this context. The following functions appear to be designed specifically to address conversion of DateTime objects in a flexible and standards compliant way.

```
XmlConvert.ToDateTime(string, System.Xml.XmlDateTimeSerializationMode)


XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime, System.Xml.XmlDateTimeSerializationMode)
```

The following enumeration member seems especially useful in the case that you want to preserve the original time zone information:

```
System.Xml.XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.RoundtripKind
```

Here are links to documentation for the functions on MSDN:

[XmlConvert.ToDateTime(string, System.Xml.XmlDateTimeSerializationMode)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162342.aspx)

[XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime, System.Xml.XmlDateTimeSerializationMode)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162344.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToString(TimeStamp, System.Xml.XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc))
```